# Why なくなる not なくなった

Tags: meaning

This question is about understanding なくなる here. From my understanding なる is an instantaneous verb (not sure the term) so if なくなった was used it would imply they have lost their confidence. But if they use なくなる then does that just mean "I'm going to lose my self confidence" or something like "I've lost some of my confidence".

> 「そんなにお強いのですか」
>
> 「稽古にならないぐらいに強かった。はっきり言って自分の自信が**なくなる**」

Comment: Hi, welcome to Japanese SE. Is there [more context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important?cb=1) you can add to the question? Where did you see these lines?

Answer (score 2):

This なくなる is a "generic" description that is true in the present and the future, not a description of a certain event in the past. So something like "He/She makes me lose my confidence" is close.